# Comparing the R-squared of five related linear regression models

Tags: regression, r-squared, model-comparison

Suppose one has a data set containing samples about three variables, X, Y, Z, and fits the following five linear regression models:

1. Y~X+Z
2. Y~X+Z/X
3. Y/X~Z
4. Y/X~Z/X
5. Y/X~X+Z/X

Here, A/B denotes the residual from regressing A on B.

Note that all regression models do not include an intercept.

The question asks one to determine the $R^2$ of these five models in terms of their ranks.

My thoughts so far:

1. $R^2$ of model 1 = $R^2$ of model 2

This should hold whether or not X and Z are perfectly correlated, as the span of X, Z is the same as the span of X, Z/X.

2. $R^2$ of model 4 = $R^2$ of model 5

In model 5, X and Z/X are orthogonal, and thus Z/X does not have any variation along X.

Also, Y/X has removed all variation along X as well.

Hence the coefficient of X would be 0, and the model is equivalent to model 4.

Thus we are really comparing model 1, 3, and 5.

Any thoughts on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Are these "observations" assumptions explicitly made in the question or are they equalities you believe to hold in general?

Comment: They are equalities that I believe to hold; thanks for the question, I have augmented those two points with more details.

Comment: Those remarks complicate your question because they are not true.